# Are the "Guests" character Mechs indestructible?

Tags: battletech

I just played a mission with Kamea and

> her Atlas mech.
>  The mission where you try to get Lord Madeira back from the Taurians.

The mech ended up losing its arms and the right torso.

Will that mech be brand new, with its standard weapon if I ever get Kamea as a guest pilot in that mech? That is, if there's another mission she will join with that Mech.

Comment: I think what you are really asking is "will guest mechs auto-repair the next time i see them?"  Clearly they are not indestructible, if they die, the mission usually fails.

Comment: @Kobold_Warlord I want to know if they'll repair with the same equipment. In my question, the mech has weapon that I can't, yet or will never, buy on the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, guest mechs are indestructible. They will return in future missions.

Minor spoiler:

> At certain points in the story campaign you will be rewarded with special mechs. They appear on the battlefield earlier but even if they are destroyed or damaged there they will be give to you intact, including any special weaponry.

Bigger spoiler:

> You will get a special highlander with unique weapons after raiding the SLDF citadel and after completing the story campaign you willl get Kamea's Atlas.

Comment: Will she be back with that mech in later mission? If she is and it is still equipped as if nothing happened, then that answer my question.

Comment: Yes, she will be, and yes it is. Even if it is destroyed the equipment will be the same in the event described in the bigger spoiler section